# Pre-1978 short story or poem about a football game with no officiating mistakes

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember the name or the author, but the plot is that human officials have either been replaced by robots or every play is video reviewed. The point of the story is that the game couldn't progress because every little error/infraction was caught and penalized.

Comment: Do you have any more information you could add, try going through the checklist [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and seeing if you can add anything.